# What is quickest way to send data from server to client?

Tags: gwt, requestfactory

I need to send large amount of data from server to client (list of around 3000 doubles).
Currently I'm using `RequestFactory`, but it's taking too much time (around 5 secs, where preparing data to send takes around 0.2 secs).

Is it any quicker way ? or shall I think more about reducing amount of data?

Comment: Are you running this in devmode? Because devmode is notoriously slow with things like this.

Comment: Danny: those results were not in devmode